# is it possible to delete multiple table data in single query ?(used database is MEMSQL)

Tags: singlestore

i used inner join with delete statement. but i could see the error like "operation delete from multiple table is not allowed".

Delete  T1 , T2 from Table1 T1  inner join Table T2
   on T1.id =T2.id 
   where t1.id = 17 ;

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't. See the documentation about the [`DELETE` statement](https://docs.memsql.com/v6.8/reference/sql-reference/data-manipulation-language-dml/delete/):

> Although `DELETE` supports referencing multiple tables using either joins or subqueries, MemSQL only supports deleting from one table in a `DELETE` statement.